# Get data from an activity in AppWidget after clear memory

Tags: android

I have encountered a problem that I built an AppWidget which gets data from an activity through a service. But after I clear phone memory, the service can't get any data. I think the activity has been killed, so the service get null data.

I'm wondering is there anyway to get the data in my activity again? (Maybe restart the activity?) But I don't want to use SharedPreferences because it can only use to store primitives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store data, u need service ruining in background.
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int, android.app.Notification)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29)
And to comunicate with serive use BroadcastReciver.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've seen the similar solution before, 
so I should modify my code into a service.
By the way, 
is it possible that I want to use SQLite's functionality through a service?